# Why not possible limiting gas but forwarding ether in creating this contract from Solidity documentation

Tags: contract-invocation, payable, constructor

In the Solidity docs [Creating contracts via new](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new) there is an example:

```
contract D {
    uint x;
    function D(uint a) public payable {
        x = a;
    }
}
```

and it states in the accompanying text:

> As seen in the example, it is possible to forward Ether while creating an instance of D using the .value() option, but it is not possible to limit the amount of gas.

Why not?